# Running PHP and Pyramid on one web server

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to have both PHP and Pyramid available on our web server. We're currently running Apache with mod_php on a CentOS-based VPS but we're now looking into developing our website using Pyramid which is a web framework for Python. However, we need to keep PHP for our forums which is at /forums. Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

Install [modwsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationInstructions). You can then serve applications using both Python and PHP from the same Apache server.

You'd then need to configure Apache's [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) to serve multiple sites. There's some advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi/1553751#1553751) that relates to running modwsgi and mod_php under the same Apache server; it recommends running modwsgi in daemon mode.